# How to output a comment using display

Tags: scheme, guile

I'm using scheme to output some s-expressions to a port and I would really like
to add comments to the stream I'm writing.

As the `;` character will comment everything after I'm unsure how to actually
do this, a comment is not an s-expression so quoting would not work

```
(display ;some comment) ; obviously not working
(display ';some comment) ; does not make sense
(display '(;some comment)) ; could make sense, does not work
```

Comment: Why not `(display ";some comment")`?

Comment: I guess you can feel my bewilderment  right now, this was so easy but I was thinking too much

Answer (score 3):

You can escape `;` using string quotes.

`(display ";some comment")` works.